# <codeBase> element equivalent in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm in a position where two different 3rd party libraries use different versions of Newtonsoft.Json, which are incompatible. For a regular application with a web.config or app.config, I can solve this using the `<codeBase>` tag to resolve the different versions. How do I do this in Azure Functions, when there is no app- or web.config? Would I have to resort to to the `AssemblyResolve` event or is there some mechanism to do the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known gap, there is no binding redirect support in Azure Functions yet.

Study [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/992) to see the discussion from the team.

[This repository](https://github.com/paulbatum/functions-assembly-loading-catalog) shows some workarounds that you can apply, or will be able to apply in the future.